# Running Azure node.js Tools on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, azure

I have followed [these](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/command-line-tools/) instructions.

And as far as I can tell I have successfully installed node.js azure tools. No error - nothing to suggest it failed.

However, I cannot, and the documentation says, simple run "azure"...

Maybe there is something I am missing with node.js?

Comment: More details... what exactly did you do? `npm install -g azure`? What's the output of that command? Does it look like it succeeded? What happens when you run `azure`? Is the command not found, or do you get an error message?

Comment: npm install -g azure works fine as far as I can tell. azure command is not found

Comment: Do other npm modules work for you? (If you do `npm install -g express` and then try to run `expross`, does that work?)

Comment: thanks, good idea... so I installed express and it worked. Adds an softlink in /usr/local/bin/express pointing to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express/bin/express, when I install azure it does not create this executable.

Comment: Did you run npm install with sudo? Sometimes I've seen weird behavior when you do that...

Comment: It only works when I run it with sudo

Comment: The documentation calls out the fact that you need to run npm using sudo on Linux. is everything working now? if not, just ensure that you're using v0.6.20 there were breaking changes to Node past this version.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems you may be experiencing.

First of all, I would ensure you are running Node.js v0.6.20. You can do this by opening the command prompt and running:

`node -v`

You should have `v0.6.20` echoed back.

If this doesn't work, you may be missing a path variable to Node.js or the NPM cache. Verify the Environment variables exist by running [in the command prompt]:

`path`

you should see two paths:

- `%appdata%\npm`

[x64 Machine]

- `%programfiles(x86)%\nodejs\`

[x86 Machine]

- `%programfiles%\nodejs\`

If this doesn't work, I would check to ensure that the `azure` module was loaded into the `%appdata%\npm\node_modules` directory.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the ubuntu in the title, these are Windows instructions.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the PATH issue. In my case, the azure program is located at  ~/.npm-global/bin.

run "export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin". Or just add to bash source file